# Reset an asp.net validation control via javascript?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, validation, reset

How do I reset an asp.net validation control via JavaScript?  The current code sample clears the error message text but does not reset the validation control for the next form submission.

```
var cv= document.getElementById("<%= MyValidationContorl.ClientID %>");
cv.innerHTML = '';
```

**Update:**

Here is the full code sample of the form.  I can not seem to get the validation controls fire off on another form submission:

```
function ClearData() {
    var cv = document.getElementById("<%= MyValidationContorl.ClientID %>");
    cv.innerHTML = '';
}

<html>
   <form>
       <asp:TextBox id="MyTextControl" runat="server" />
       <asp:CustomValidator ID="MyValidationContorl" runat="server" />
       <input type="button" onclick="javascript:ClearCCData(); return false;" runat="server" />
   </form>
</html>
```

Comment: @azamsharp -- I mean to enable the start the validation process from the beginning.

Answer (score 40):

Page validation is fired every time you do a post, what appears to be the problem is that you are clearing the validator content `cv.innerHTML = '';`, this way your validator message is lost forever and you'll think validation is not firing again.

and for @Glennular answer, the code does not handle the validator `Display` property, if its set to `Dynamic` the validator will be toggled using `validator.style.display`, but if its set to `None` or `Inline` then `validator.style.visibility` property will be used instead.

Its better to use asp.net `ValidatorUpdateDisplay` instead,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Page_ClientValidateReset() {
        if (typeof (Page_Validators) != "undefined") {
            for (var i = 0; i < Page_Validators.length; i++) {
                var validator = Page_Validators[i]; 
                validator.isvalid = true;
                ValidatorUpdateDisplay(validator);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Update** : Reset Validation Summaries

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Page_ValidationSummariesReset(){
    if (typeof(Page_ValidationSummaries) == "undefined")
            return;
    for (var i = 0; i < Page_ValidationSummaries.length; i++)
            Page_ValidationSummaries[i].style.display = "none";

}
</script>
```

Comment: Hi @MK .. your function works great .. It resets all the validators as I wanted but it doesn't reset the validation summary. Do you have any code that might do that job? Thanks a lot. I am desperately needing it.

Comment: @LaurenceNyein I updated the answer to include a reset validation summaries method.

Answer (score 17):

This one resets all validators in all validation groups.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Page_ClientValidate('');
</script>
```

Comment: If you use this, make sure you have a `ValidationGroup` defined for all validators... otherwise it will trigger validators without a group. If you're really lazy and don't want to define a validation group for every element, you could make up a random string that won't be used as a validation group like so: `Page_ClientValidate('reset-all');`

Comment: Empty string would fire all validators.

Comment: That does not *reset the validators*. That **fires validation** against an empty ValidationGroup, which could well be present, as @dhsto says.

Comment: There is a difference between Page_ClientValidate() and Page_ClientValidate('')

Comment: It would be even better if you pass a string that can never be a name of a validation group (e.g. a GUID). This will cause ASP.NET to perform a validation on a non-existing validation group and thus reset all validators.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following chunk of code :

```
$("#<%= txtUserSettingsEmailRequiredValidator.ClientID %>").css("display", "none");
```

I hope this will work as it worked for me. :)

Answer (score -1):

Here's code to reset all validators

```
function CleanForm() {
    document.forms[0].reset(); 

    for (i = 0; i < Page_Validators.length; i++) {
        Page_Validators[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }

    return false;
}
```

or a single one:

```
document.getElementById("<%= MyValidationContorl.ClientID %>").style.visibility
 = 'hidden';
```

Comment: It hides the validation controls, but when I try another form submission it does not fire off the validation controls again.

Answer (score -3):

Using the `Page_Validators[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';`
Don't work for me so I use this line of code instead: `Page_Validators[i].enabled = false;`

```
if (sFirstName == "" && sLastName == "") 
    {

        alert('Reminder: Please first enter student ID to search for the student information before filling out the rest of the form field values');
        //Disable all require field validation coontrol on the form so the user could continue to use the Lookup student function.
        document.forms[0].reset();
        for (i = 0; i < Page_Validators.length; i++) {
            //Page_Validators[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';
            Page_Validators[i].enabled = false;
        }
        return false;
    }
    else 
    {
        alert('Student Name = ' + sFirstName + ' ' + sLastName);
        document.forms[0].reset();

        for (i = 0; i < Page_Validators.length; i++) {
            //Page_Validators[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';
            Page_Validators[i].enabled = true;
        }
        return true;
    }
```