# How to Hide error message of a asp custom validator

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using asp requiredfieldvalidator. I want the required field validator to fire only when a checkbox on my form is checked.

When the checkbox is fired, the validator works as expected and error message shows up but when the checkbox is unchecked the errormessage that showed up stays on the screen. I have tried different options like validator.resetForm(); disabling the validator, hiding the validator but the error message stays on the screen form. Here is the simplified version of my code:

```
<script src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function enableDisableControls(value) {
      var enabledSilentPost = $("#<%=chkEnableSilentPost.ClientID%>").attr("checked");
      var validatorControl = $("#<%=valApprovalURL.ClientID%>")[0];

      ValidatorEnable(validatorControl, enabledSilentPost);

      // If the checkbox is false then assume that the 
      if (!enabledSilentPost) {
        validatorControl.enabled = false;
      }
    }

$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#<%=chkEnableSilentPost.ClientID%>").click(function () {
    enableDisableControls();
  });

  enableDisableControls();
});

</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
  <div>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkEnableSilentPost" runat="server" Width="250px" Text="Enable" />
    <asp:Label ID="lblApprovalURL" runat="server" Text="URL" CssClass="controllabel" meta:resourcekey="lblApprovalURLResource"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtApprovalURL" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="valApprovalURL" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtApprovalURL" ErrorMessage="Please enter Valid Text" Text="*"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <actk:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="extApprovalURL" TargetControlID="valApprovalURL" runat="server" Enabled="True"></actk:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: how about adding check change event to checkbox and inside the event write this code: valApprovalURL.Enabled = chkEnableSilentPost.Checked;

Comment: Well the code inside the click event does exactly that. Please note that disabling the validation control does not clear the error message and that's the problem. Just to clarify, if lets say user click on check box and did not enter the value in textbox, the user will get an error message. If user unchecks the checkbox then he/she would expect the error message to go away but it does not.

Comment: Well as far as i know the validation message is handled through javascript that is a client side and server doesn't know anything about it. Put CauseValidation="false" inside the checkbox.

Comment: This seems to answer the question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915830/reset-an-asp-net-validation-control-via-javascript

Answer (score 0):

I am was able to get the validators to react by doing the following.  The Validator was pretty simpe, but I had to predict the ID of the Extender in order for it to work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#<%=chkEnableSilentPost.ClientID %>').click(function () {
                $("#<%=valApprovalURL.ClientID %>").toggle(this.checked);
                $("#extApprovalURL_popupTable").toggle(this.checked);
            });
        });

    </script>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server" />
        <div>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkEnableSilentPost" runat="server" Width="250px" Text="Enable" />
            <asp:Label ID="lblApprovalURL" runat="server" Text="URL" CssClass="controllabel" meta:resourcekey="lblApprovalURLResource"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtApprovalURL" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="valApprovalURL" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtApprovalURL" ErrorMessage="Please enter Valid Text" Text="*"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="extApprovalURL" TargetControlID="valApprovalURL" runat="server" Enabled="True"></asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: I don't want the postbacks. I want the validation to work on clientside only. Please see my comments to irfan's response.

Comment: That solution works but it needs guess work to get the id for popupTable. I was wondering if there is another way to get to the pop table without the guesswork, Like some property on the validator control that can get the pop up table.

Comment: I looked and couldn't find one.  Please let me know if you find one :)