# How update ValdationSummary using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validationsummary

Here is aspx :

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt_name" runat="server" CssClass="input_class" ValidationGroup="A"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfv_txt_name" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter your name." ValidationGroup="A" Text="The field is required." Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txt_name" CssClass="rfv_class" ToolTip="The field is required."></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:Button ID="btn_contact" runat="server" Text="Send Message" ValidationGroup="A" />
<asp:ValidationSummary ID="Validation_Summary_1" runat="server" ValidationGroup="A"/>
```

When `txt_name` is empty & click on `btn_contact`, `Validation_Summary_1's message = Please enter your name.` + `RequiredFieldValidator's text = The field is required.` show up.

Now when i click on `txt_name` & type something & click outside of this textbox `RequiredFieldValidator's text = The field is required.` is vanished.

But `Validation_Summary_1's message = Please enter your name.` is still there until i click on `btn_contact`.

How can i update `Validation_Summary_1` by click on outside of `txt_name`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915830/reset-an-asp-net-validation-control-via-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the code below for client side validation & also update ValidationSummary in JavaScript :

```
Page_ClientValidate("Your_Validation_Group");
```

[Page_ClientValidate - Use This Method From Javascript for ASP.Net Client Side Validation](https://smsohan.com/blog/2008/05/11/pageclientvalidate-use-this-method-from/)

With the code below you can check if page is valid or not :

```
Page_IsValid
```